# AWS Allow only health checks on port 80

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Is it possible to restrict via security groups that only health checks (or AWS services in general) are allowed through the port 80?

I don't want to open this port for the whole world :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. The security group (SG) on EC2 instances (I guess you are using ec2), need to allow [inbound connections from SG of your load balancer (LB)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html#sg-rules-elb). This way only connections from LB to the EC2 instances will be allowed.